# android сделать recyclerview карусель?

Tags: android, recyclerview

android сделать recyclerview карусель? что бы показывалась 3 item(рисунк и  текст) , что она прокручивалась, и не выбиралось полторы item, как это реализовать через recyclerview ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая карусель в андроиде называется CoverFlow. На github-е есть много решений, [вот](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow) одно из самого юзабельного и гибкого

Comment: минус твоей библиотеки в том, что она поддерживает с 15 версий, мне дано с 14

Comment: пожалуйста. Гуглите под 14